# Book Identification: Dragons as war machines

Tags: story-identification, books

Read the book once in the late 90's The only things I can remember are:

- Dragons were some sort of war machine (built and maintained, rather then real, living creatures)
- A bunch of somewhat magical creatures working in a factory.
- The pilot of the dragon has small needles inserted into their arms.
- Lastly, I'm associating the color green with the cover.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure but all that comes to mind is [The Iron Dragon's Daughter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Dragon%27s_Daughter). I'm not sure if it is the same book.

Comment: That's the one, thank you. Don't remember particularly enjoying it back then, but it has been bugging me for a while, going to give it another shot.

Comment: The Dragons of Babel takes place in the same world, and is quite a good read.